# Postfix errors - stopped sending emails

Tags: postfix

Everything was OK, every email has been delivered.

But in last days, emails stopped working, twice. I only rebooted server, and it started working again, but i think, that somewhere in here is better solution.

Errors :

```
Oct 11 08:39:02 vps0241 postfix/smtp[18996]: warning: 8E39925410: flush service failure
Oct 11 08:44:25 vps0241 postfix/smtp[19987]: warning: connect to mysql server 127.0.0.1: Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111)
Oct 11 08:44:25 vps0241 postfix/smtp[19987]: warning: mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_relaydomains.cf: table lookup problem
Oct 11 08:44:25 vps0241 postfix/smtp[19987]: warning: 54534253C3: flush service failure
Oct 11 08:44:25 vps0241 postfix/smtp[19987]: warning: mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_relaydomains.cf: table lookup problem
Oct 11 08:44:25 vps0241 postfix/smtp[19987]: warning: 1980425473: flush service failure
Oct 11 08:44:25 vps0241 postfix/smtp[19987]: warning: mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_relaydomains.cf: table lookup problem
Oct 11 08:44:25 vps0241 postfix/smtp[19987]: warning: 876F12546A: flush service failure
Oct 11 08:44:25 vps0241 postfix/smtp[19988]: warning: connect to mysql server 127.0.0.1: Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111)
Oct 11 08:44:25 vps0241 postfix/smtp[19988]: warning: mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_relaydomains.cf: table lookup problem
Oct 11 08:44:25 vps0241 postfix/smtp[19988]: warning: 8E39925410: flush service failure
```

Comment: When emails stopped been delivered,did you check if MySQL was still running? It appears to have been a connection problem to MySQL. Check you MySQL logs,to tell what time the MySQL service stopped and the time emails stopped been delivered.

Comment: Websites are using same database, mysql was ok.

Answer (score 2):

> connect to mysql server 127.0.0.1: Can't connect to MySQL server on
>   '127.0.0.1' (111)

states that there is a problem with the database connection specified in /etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_relaydomains.cf